# Java caret not going to the next line correctly in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

When I write a Switch statement in Java (I use IntelliJ IDEA), the blinking cursor, or caret, doesn't go to the next line correctly. It's not really a huge problem, but just an annoyance I'm not sure how to fix.

When I write a case for a switch code block:

```
switch(switchValue){
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Value was 1");
        break;
}
```

After the 'break;', when I enter the cursor stays inside the case 1 code block

```
switch(switchValue){
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Value was 1");
        break;
        <-- The cursor goes here
}
```

And when I backspace to move it back so I can make a new case, the line just goes back to the end of the break;

```
switch(switchValue){
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Value was 1");
        break;<-- cursor goes here
}
```

The only way I can move it to create a new case 2 is to manually use my directional keys 4 spaces after I press enter. Is there a keyboard shortcut where I can create a new case without the extra steps?

```
switch(switchValue){
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Value was 1");
        break;
    <-- cursor goes here and after I use the directional keys    
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Value was 2");
        break;
}
```

This was a really obscure minor issue I can't seem to find the answer for.

Comment: It doesn’t indent when you write the new case statement? It does for me.

Comment: I think I was just having some ocd about how the cursor moves. I just tested it and figured out that if I just write "case 2" after the "break;", it'll just automatically delete the 4 spaces and correctly create a new case.

I answered my own problem the moment I submitted the question. Oops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I fixed my own issue after posting the question.

If I just type "case 2:" after going to the next line after the "break;", IntelliJ IDEA will automatically format the case and move it to the correct position without any hassle.

```
switch(switchValue){
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Value was 1");
        break;
        case 2:
}
```

The moment you finish the case statement with the colon, the editor will automatically format the line and move the statement to the correct position.

```
switch(switchValue){
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Value was 1");
        break;
    case 2:
}
```

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178127.